# Different types of sorting for 8 Puzzle

Tags: python

I was trying different types of sorting algorithm for 8 Puzzle in python with calculation of manhattan distance. Done with bubble and merge. Specifically trying to achieve quick sort.

Below code gives me the error:

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'NoneType' and 'list'
```

Queue is list of nodes of 8 Puzzle states having elements (present state, parent node, depth, pathcost, manhattanDistance, MisplacedTilesDistance )

Any pointers for improvement

```
def quickSort(queue, length):
    less = []
    pivotList = []
    more = []
    returnList = []
    if length <= 1:
        return queue
    else:
        if queue == []:
            return
        else:    
            pivot = queue[0][3] + queue[0][4]

        for i in queue:

            if i[3]+i[4] < pivot:
                less.append(i)
                print less
                input("yes")
            elif i[3]+i[4] > pivot:
                more.append(i)
            else:
                pivotList.append(i)

        less = quickSort(less, length)
        more = quickSort(more, length)
        #returnList.append(less, pivotList, more)
        return less + pivotList + more
```

Comment: Please include the **full** traceback of the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are trying to implement the Quicksort algorithm as in Wikipedia. Here is a sample implementation in Python. You can customize it as per your needs.

```
def quickSort(queue):
    lengthOfQueue = len(queue)
    if lengthOfQueue <= 1: return queue
    pivotLocation = lengthOfQueue // 2
    pivot, lesser, greater = queue[pivotLocation], [], []
    for i in range(lengthOfQueue):
        if (i == pivotLocation): continue
        if (queue[i] <= pivot): lesser.append(queue[i])
        else: greater.append(queue[i])
    return quickSort(lesser) + [queue[pivotLocation]] + quickSort(greater)

print quickSort([3, 7, 8, 5, 2, 1, 9, 5, 4])
```

**Output**

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 5, 7, 8, 9]
```

**Explanation**

**Pseudo Code:**

```
  function quicksort('array')
      if length('array') ≤ 1
          return 'array'  // an array of zero or one elements is already sorted
      select and remove a pivot element 'pivot' from 'array'  // see 'Choice of pivot' below
      create empty lists 'less' and 'greater'
      for each 'x' in 'array'
          if 'x' ≤ 'pivot' then append 'x' to 'less'
          else append 'x' to 'greater'
      return concatenate(quicksort('less'), list('pivot'), quicksort('greater')) // two recursive calls
```

Lets see how the program fits this pseudo code.

```
len(queue)
```

This is used to find the length of queue. http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#len

If the length is lesser than or equal to 1, we return the queue as it is. It means that, either the queue is empty or it has only one element. This is the base condition for the recursion.

We choose a simple pivot, the middle element of the queue. So, we find the location of pivot with

```
pivotLocation = lengthOfQueue // 2
```

Then we pick the pivot element and create two empty lists, lesser and greater.

```
pivot, lesser, greater = queue[pivotLocation], [], []
```

Now we have to create two arrays, one will have the elements lesser than or equal to the pivot and the other one will have elements greater than pivot. We do that with this loop.

```
for i in range(lengthOfQueue):
    if (i == pivotLocation): continue
    if (queue[i] <= pivot): lesser.append(queue[i])
    else: greater.append(queue[i])
```

We dont want to send pivot element to either lesser or greater. So we skip pivot element like this.

```
if (i == pivotLocation): continue
```

Then we sort both the arrays using the same algorithm, concatenate the results and return that.

```
return quickSort(lesser) + [queue[pivotLocation]] + quickSort(greater)
```

Comment: Can you explain the usage of this code in your solution:                                                                                                           if (i == pivotLocation): continue

Comment: @user2803846 Please check now, I have included explanation.

Answer (score 2):

```
        if queue == []:
            return
```

You forgot to return something here.

Comment: You have beaten me to it.